# Derivative of vector wrt vector

Tags: calculus, matrices

Let $x^{T}=[X_{1}\  X_{2}], \ h(x)=x$. Then,

$$\dfrac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x}  = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial h(x)}\begin{bmatrix}X_{1}\\ X_{2}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial X_{1}}  X_{1} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial X_{2}}  X_{1}\\ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial X_{1}}X_{2}\ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial X_{2}}X_{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

The derivative therefore is 2x2 while x is 2x1.   If we were to therefore use this result for something like gradient descent, how would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better if you use Mathjax because it is not so clear what you are asking. Anyway, if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to\mathbb{R}^m $ is  vector function $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})= \left(f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}), \cdots, f_m(\mathbf{x}) \right)$,  the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_function#Derivative_of_an_n-dimensional_vector_function)  of $\mathbf {f}$  with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ is the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1 }& \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n }\\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1 }& \cdots & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n }\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1 }& \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n }\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
usually called the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).